# How to handle Check Box clicks in a cell based NSOutlineView

Tags: swift, cocoa, nsoutlineview

I'd like to handle clicks on check boxes in NSOutlineView.
Check boxes are Check Box Cell of type NSButtonCell.
I'm able to set the initial state in:

```
optional func outlineView(_ outlineView: NSOutlineView,
                            willDisplayCell cell: AnyObject,
                            forTableColumn tableColumn: NSTableColumn?,
                            item item: AnyObject)
```

Now, how can i execute a function when the state of the check box changes?
I searched the internet but i can't find out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this to set values from the table:

[DragNDropOutlineView: implementing drag and drop in an NSOutlineView](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/DragNDropOutlineView/Introduction/Intro.html)

```
// Optional method: needed to allow editing.
- (void)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)ov setObjectValue:(id)object forTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn byItem:(id)item  {
AAPLSimpleNodeData *nodeData = [item representedObject];

// Here, we manipulate the data stored in the node.
if ([[tableColumn identifier] isEqualToString:COLUMID_IS_SELECTABLE]) {
    nodeData.selectable = [object boolValue];
}
```

}

Another way is to set target and action of each cell in:

```
optional func outlineView(_ outlineView: NSOutlineView,
                        willDisplayCell cell: AnyObject,
                        forTableColumn tableColumn: NSTableColumn?,
                        item item: AnyObject)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to reload the item corresponding to the checkbox cell. Please take a look on this API https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSOutlineView_Class/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000110-SW7

Comment: Sorry, i don't understand what this has to do with my question ^^'

Comment: You have to handle the action from checkbox . You can do it in 2 ways. 1) You can simply make an IBAction in your xib from your cell to your controller or do it in programetically. When you get action on your check box cell update your modal based on the state and reload the item